# Entity Framework many to many on same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

I am using C# and Entity Framework, code first migrations.

I've got a class, `user`, which has a many to many relation with itself, with the property `Friends`. Currently I have this code responsible for creating that database structure and the relationship itself.

```
[InverseProperty("ReverseFriends")]
public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
[InverseProperty("Friends")]
public virtual ICollection<User> ReverseFriends { get; set; }
```

However I suspect/hope there is a way to do this with only a single navigation property, instead of two. Is this the case? Or is the way I have done so above the way to do a many to many on a single table?

Comment: This is interesting, for a many-to-many, EF will create the extra table. Did you get your code running and did EF create a table called FriendsFriends? (if your class is called Friends that is.

Comment: My Class is called user, it did create the extra table named `UserUsers`, and it runs just fine. I am just wondering / hoping there is a way to do this with a single navigation property.

Comment: I conclude you did it totally fine because a many to many can only be maintained over 2 tables. The beauty of EF is that you do not have to maintain this yourself. You do need keep an eye on (lazy)loading else it could become interesting when you have a bigger DB. It will load all friends of friends and given that everyone is everyones friend you load the complete table.

Comment: I do think you can do one of your links over fluent api..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model and data annotations are just fine.

> However I suspect/hope there is a way to do this with only a single navigation property, instead of two.

Negative. Relationships always include **two** entities (although they could be of one and the same type as here). And many to many w/o fluent API require **two** navigation properties.

Imagine many to many relationship between two entities `A` and `B`:

```
public class A
{
    [InverseProperty("As")]
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [InverseProperty("Bs")]
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `InverseProperty` annotation is optional in this case because EF can automatically correlate the two navigation properties and form a single many to many relationship.

Now let substitute `A == B`. What we got is:

```
public partial class A
{
    [InverseProperty("As")]
    public ICollection<A> Bs { get; set; }
}

public partial class A
{
    [InverseProperty("Bs")]
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

or after consolidation:

```
public class A
{
    [InverseProperty("As")]
    public ICollection<A> Bs { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Bs")]
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. exactly what you did.

If you want to create the relationship with just one navigation property, then you must use fluent API. For instance, if you want to keep only `Friends`, e.g.

```
public class User
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

you would need the following fluent config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
   .WithMany(); // no inverse navigation property
```

But note that while this allows you to define the relationship, the `Friends` property will still contain only the elements from the join table where let say `UserId` equals `User.Id`. It won't contain the elements of the join table where `FriendId` equals `User.Id`.

The best is to keep both navigation properties and explicitly configure the join table, e.g.

```
public class User
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FriendOf { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.Friends)
   .WithMany(u => u.FriendOf);
   .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserFriends")
       .MapLeftKey("UserId")
       .MapRightKey("FriendId"));
```

This allows you to get all join table elements where user is either `UserId` or `FriendId`, i.e. all user friends:

```
var query = db.Users.Select(u => new
{
    User = u,
    AllFriends = u.Friends.Concat(u.FriendOf).ToList(),
});
```